# How to save queryset by user in new models from our created models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have some models and every models have many queryset.

models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    match_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_team = models.ForeignKey('FirstTeam', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    second_team = models.ForeignKey('SecondTeam', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tournament_name = models.ForeignKey('TournamentName', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    match_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    match_stated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    mega_league = models.ManyToManyField('MegaLeague', blank=True)
```

I have also many models `class` like this. In `admin` site I created data for every `models` and then I show all queryset on different `templates` correctly.

Now I want to make same duplicate models `class`(same fields also) where data is stored by `user`. When `user` select our own queryset in `templates` then that queryset will store in new duplicate `models`(same class and same fields) and every queryset will different different for different `users`. That means every `user` can store their queryset by selecting our own queryset from `templates`.

How can i do this??

Comment: The question is not very clear, but I think you need not create duplicate models for each user, you just have to use a foreign key relationship to User model on the particular model you're thinking of duplicating and then you can filter records like ModelName.objects.filter(user=particular_user)

Comment: @Mehak using foreign key it's not possible. Users need to see their own selected queryset from my Models. They select queryset from templates which I made in my Models by using admin site. Then i will also show them their selected queryset in another template for different Users the data will be different because users can select different queryset. so i need same duplicate Models where the selected query will be stored by every Users.

Comment: The problem is that we can't create a django Model dynamically yet. You can only add rows of data to an existing model. You can use relations to store which user selected which data, if foreign key does not serve your purpose, maybe Manytomany field will do.

Comment: @Mehak thank you. I will try.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman sir, Can you help me please??